# ROS Graph Messages Build

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosdep, buiding-errors

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm ROS1 beginner, and I've been trying to get moveit installed and running. When running `catkin_make`, cmake fails with:

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'moveit_commander'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(moveit/moveit_commander)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rviz_visual_tools'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(rviz_visual_tools)
-- Could NOT find graph_msgs (missing: graph_msgs_DIR)
-- Could not find the required component 'graph_msgs'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install 
   the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "graph_msgs" with
  any of the following names:

   graph_msgsConfig.cmake
```

I've tried installing it with `rosdep install rosgraph_msgs`, which says the installation was successful. However, when I run `roswtf`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: The core ROS message libraries (std_msgs and rosgraph_msgs) have not been built.
```

I then tried cloning the source for the rosgraph_msgs repo from `https://github.com/ros/ros_comm_msgs`, but it doesn't provide a `rosinstall` file or a `CMakeLists.txt` file.

For further info here is the output of `env | grep -i ros`:

```
PATH=/home/ttt/anaconda3/envs/py27/bin:/opt/ros/melodic/bin:/home/ttt/anaconda3/bin:/home/ttt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/ttt/Programming/ROS/rostest2/devel:/opt/ros/melodic
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ttt/Programming/ROS/rostest2/devel/lib:/opt/ros/melodic/lib
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/ttt/Programming/ROS/rostest2/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/melodic/lib/pkgconfig
PYTHONPATH=/home/ttt/Programming/ROS/rostest2/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages:/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
ROS_DISTRO=melodic
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/melodic/etc/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/ttt/Programming/ROS/rostest2/src:/opt/ros/melodic/share
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=2
ROS_VERSION=1
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/ttt/Programming/ROS/rostest2/devel/share/common-lisp
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335514/ros-graph-messages-build/) by [toblorone](https://answers.ros.org/users/47341/toblorone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I've tried installing it with `rosdep install rosgraph_msgs`, which says the installation was successful.

The package you're looking for is not [rosgraph_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/rosgraph_msgs), but [graph_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/graph_msgs). Those are two different packages.

You should be able to install the latter with:

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-graph-msgs
```

Please also note that `rosdep install` deals with package dependencies. Not packages themselves directly.

Use `apt` to install packages, or build them in your workspace (but don't do the latter, unless absolutely necessary). See also #q320046.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [toblorone](https://answers.ros.org/users/47341/toblorone/) on 2019-10-16**:
Ah ok, I noticed the repository [here](https://github.com/davetcoleman/graph_msgs) but I figured it couldn't be it as it seemed to have very little activity ha. Thanks so much for the help!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-16**:
I'm also wondering why you're building MoveIt from sources, but that is a different question.

**Comment by [toblorone](https://answers.ros.org/users/47341/toblorone/) on 2019-10-16**:
I was following the tutorial [here](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html). It seems to have me clone several repos into my catkin workspace `/src/` folder, then run catkin_make.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-16**:
Have you seen the notice at the top of the page:

> This is the latest version, which is actively developed. For beginners, we recommmend the stable Melodic tutorials. If you are still running a Kinetic release, please use the Kinetic tutorials.